# HTML5/JavaScript - How to add a timestamp attribute to video source?

Tags: javascript, html, video

Having never used HTML or JavaScript before I'm really struggling to find an answer to this! I'm running a website for a local club which uses an online site builder so I haven't had to do any coding so far.

I want to show a timelapse video on one of the pages that updates every 30 mins via FTP (overwriting itself every time it updates). I've got the video uploading and playing fine but browsers are caching the video and not re-loading it when the page refreshes as the file name stays the same. I've done plenty of research and found that adding a random attribute, such as a timestamp, to the video src path would likely fix the issue (as per the below link) but I can't figure out how to do this.

[Force browser to update cached HTML5 video object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37265349/force-browser-to-update-cached-html5-video-object)

As it's an online website builder, the only way to add code is to insert a 'HTML/Script' element and paste the code in there, so currently I have:

```
<video width="476" height="266" controls="" autoplay="">
<source src="http://mydomain.co.uk/Weather/today.mp4" 
new="" type="video/mp4"/>
Sorry, your browser does not support our time lapse video.
</video>
```

I'm under the impression that I need some JavaScript in there to add the attribute, but as a newbie to HTML/Java I could do with some help! Thanks, Jonathan.

Comment: How do you determine the URL that is used for this video resource? You only need to modify the HTML by appending `?something=ARandomStringOrNumberOrWhateverAsLongAsItsDifferentEveryTime`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will go into the video object that you have created and append a unique string to the end of the source of the video.

I did add an ID to the source in the video object to allow easier access of the source object with javascript.

```js
var video = document.getElementById("vid");
var source = document.getElementById("vidsource");
var rndString = "?t=" + Date.now();
source.src = source.src + rndString;
video.load();
```

```html
<video id="vid" width="476" height="266" controls="" autoplay="">
  <source id="vidsource" src="http://mydomain.co.uk/Weather/today.mp4" new="" type="video/mp4" />Sorry, your browser does not support our time lapse video.
</video>
```

Comment: don't forget to call `video.load()` after you changed a `<source>`'s src.

Comment: Thanks both, this looks to have worked for both desktop and mobile browsers! I added <script> before the java code (which the editor automatically changed to <script type="javascript">) and </script> after the java code. The editor also surrounded the java code block with <![CDATA[ before and ]]> after. I'm not sure why it did this but it still looks to work. Thanks.